# How do I store a image BLOB in an access database after getting the name from openfiledialog?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am developing a C# application that has an Access database.  What I want to do is allow a user to select an image through an "openfiledialog." I then want to store the image in one of the table of the access database in a BLOB field.  I have searched over the internet, but found nothing helpful. I hope you can help me.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

     // textBox1.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
     // MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
     textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();

     String filename = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
     byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

     using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Policias.accdb"))

     using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
     {                 
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DetallesMunicipio(imagen) VALUES (@imagen)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen", buffer);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     }
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Porfavor selecciona una imagen");

     }

}
```

but now how can I be sure that is stored in the access database?

Comment: are you asking how after a user selects a file from an open file dialog to then save that to a database?

Comment: Yes. THis is basicalyl a very basic programmer question.

Comment: I am new in C#, so please help me, I know Java, but C# not, and @msarchet yes

Comment: I highly recommend against storing binary data in your Jet/ACE data tables. You're just asking for trouble, in my experience. Store the binary data in the file system and simply store the path/filename in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
string filename = "foo.txt"; // TODO: fetch from file dialog
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=foo.mdb"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@Name, @Data)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", buffer);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I like that both our answers together is the full answer.

Comment: thanks but if I want to store an image string change to something?

Comment: I get and error I am using the new format of Acces accdb, what can I do?

Comment: but now how can I be sure that is stored in the database Acces? my code is in the begining

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is something similar to the following.

```
using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog){
   if(fileDialog.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK){
       using (System.IO.FileInfo fileToSave = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileDialog.FilePath)){
          MemoryStream ms = System.IO.FileStream(fileToSave.FullNae, IO.FileMode.Open);
           //Here you can copy the ms over to a byte array to save into your blob in your database.
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what do "MemoryStream ms = System.IO.FileStream(fileToSave.FullNae, IO.FileMode.Open);" do?

Comment: IT creates a new MemoryStream object (basically a byte array stored in memory) by reading the contents of the selected file into the memorystream

Answer (score 0):

I would use File.ReeadAllBytes(file) and save the byte[] there in the DB.